# How to delay the load of an <a> tag in javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem that some link we show is separeted from the rest of the page itself, so the link showes up immediatly as you open the page but the page takes 2-3 seconds to load, I'm trying to delay the link (in this example it's google) so it will show up a few seconds after the page is loaded.
am I getting close?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Delay export link</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(show(), 2000);
}

function show() {
    document.getElementById("Link").style.display = "inline";
}

function exportSrc() {
   var scrt_var = "www.google.com;
  document.getElementById("Link").setAttribute("href",scrt_var);  
} 

    </script>
  </head>

   <style>
     #Link{display:none;}
    </style>

 <body window.onLoad="myFunction();">
   <a id="Link" onclick="exportSrc();" target='_blank'>
   <img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/mkw779.png">
     </a>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: There's an important difference between `foo` and `foo()`.

Comment: which one should I put in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few errors in your page which is stopping this from working:

Usually the first thing to check when something is not working is the browser console (press F12) and looks for errors. This won't fix problems with logic but should put you in a good position to start debugging things.

1. You have a missing `"` syntax error in `exportSrc` - this will show in the browser console
2. The `load` attribute in the `body` is incorrect. You should just use `onload="myFunction()"`
3. Your `setTimeout` is *calling* `show` instead of *referencing* it. Remove the `()`s.
4. Put the `<style>` tags inside the `<head>`
5. You have an extra `</div>` tag

This should work better:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Delay export link</title>
        <style>
            #Link{display:none;}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function myFunction() {
            myVar = setTimeout(show, 2000);
        }

        function show() {
            document.getElementById("Link").style.display = "inline";
        }

        function exportSrc() {
            var scrt_var = "www.google.com";
            document.getElementById("Link").setAttribute("href",scrt_var);  
        } 

        </script>
    </head>


    <body onload="myFunction();">
        <a id="Link" onclick="exportSrc();" target='_blank'>
            <img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/mkw779.png">
        </a>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<body onLoad="myFunction();">
```

Instead of window.onLoad

Comment: While inline event handlers are quite from the 1990s, they should work if you use the correct one, which is indeed `onload`, not `window.onLoad`. If it doesn't work for you, you must be testing it the wrong way.

Comment: The link just doesn't show at all, in another mode I tested I got an error saying "Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Comment: This answer is not a fix to your entire problem, it's telling you that there isn't an HTML attribute called `window.onLoad`. Please don't expect this site to just produce code you can copy and paste blindly.

Comment: I know, I was digging all day to find these commands, I have no experiance in javascript but this is the best I could do. I think I'm getting close but something is missing.. hoped to find it here but I guess I'll have to keep searching